# Unable to control the every content of an Exception object (location not available)

Tags: c#, exception, inner-exception

I have a method for manually causing the application to crash for testing purposes. It works as supposed to and the custom error page appears just as I want it to. However, I noticed that while the **outer** exception (i.e. **the** exception) provides info on location (i.e. *Api.Controllers.UtilController.Poof() in UtilController.cs, line 58* on the last line below), the **inner** one doesn't (stating but *Unknown location*, while I was led to believe [otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.source?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)). The full content of the error message rendered is as follows.

> Exception: There are no details but the error code.
> GUID: 77ad89f7-7220-43b6-8fe9-d473e18ff07b
> See outer text for general info.
> *Unknown location*
>
> Exception: This is a crash test invoked @ 07:21:15.
> See inner exception for details.
> *Api.Controllers.UtilController.Poof() in UtilController.cs, line 58*

I understand that since the inner exception is merely instantiated, not actually thrown, there's no location of its origin. I'd like to alter the location text provided from the inner exception to something custom.

Investigating the contents of the object, I found only two properties seeming to be the likely for that purpose - *Source* and *TargetSite*. However, setting those, didn't bring any change in the values (remaining *null*, despite not being read-only), so I conclude they get overwritten somehow. I also found no field with the string value corresponding to the location anywhere, even after the throw having been invoked.

```
public ActionResult Poof()
{
  string occasion = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
  string message = "This is a crash test invoked @ " + occasion + "."
    + "\nSee inner exception for details.";
  string details = "There are no details but the error code."
    + "\nGUID: " + Guid.NewGuid()
    + "\nSee outer text for general info.";

  Exception innerException = new Exception(details);
  innerException.Source = "Location as referred below.";
  // innerException.TargetSite = new DynamicMethod(...);
  Exception exception = new Exception(message, innerException);

  throw exception;
}
```

- Where are those location info strings located in the exception object?
- When/how do they get assigned?
- Can I alter them and if so how?

I've read the docs of the [exception page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in WebAPI and the general [exception object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netcore-3.1) (including the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netcore-3.1#Properties) such as [*Source*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.source?view=netcore-3.1) and [*TargetSite*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.targetsite?view=netcore-3.1) for the [*InnerException*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netcore-3.1)). I feel that I understand the contents but the reality proves otherwise. Effort in research invested, I need help clarifying the three items above.

Comment: As an aside, I wish more questions on Stack Overflowed showed this level of care and research in terms of demonstrating where you're getting your information, what you've tried, and why the results are not consistent with your expectations. (I also imagine that's part of why you have a 25k reputation—but it's still something I appreciate when I see it.) As far as your actual question, I'll be following with interest; I've stumbled across this behavior before, but it hasn't yet been a big enough concern in my applications to motivate me to try and find an answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney That's the standard I generally aim to uphold, helping others help me. Certain questions call for a bit more story, while other do not, but I always try to keep it sufficiently well written. You'll be surprised to learn, though, that I've been downvoted and reprimanded despite the quality of the question being on par with this. Some people confuse ***them** not grasping* with ***it** being hard to grasp*. So your kind owrds actually did make me happy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is the fact that only one of the exceptions is actually `thrown`.

The outer exception has a location because it was `thrown`.

The inner exception was created and added to the outer exception but the inner exception was not a thrown and caught exception. Thus will have no location information populated by the runtime.

For example, the following test example

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        string occasion = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            string details = "There are no details but the error code." + "\nGUID: " + Guid.NewGuid() + "\nSee outer text for general info.";
            Exception innerException = new Exception(details);
            innerException.Source = "Location as referred below.";
            throw innerException;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            string message = "This is a crash test invoked @ " + occasion + "." + "\nSee inner exception for details.";
            Exception exception = new Exception(message, e);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Shows the following message when the test is run

```
Result StackTrace:  
at UnitTestProject.tests.MyTestClass.MyTestMethod() in C:\...\UnitTest1.cs:line 33
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at UnitTestProject.tests.MyTestClass.MyTestMethod() in C:\...\UnitTest1.cs:line 37
Result Message: 
Test method UnitTestProject.tests.MyTestClass.MyTestMethod threw exception: 
System.Exception: This is a crash test invoked @ 20:34:49.
See inner exception for details. ---> System.Exception: There are no details but the error code.
GUID: 2a9bd143-6647-4774-9ea4-615d7f1d2f9f
See outer text for general info.
```

If the test is rewritten as follows

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        try {
            Core();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            var temp = ex; //<-- PUT BREAKPOINT HERE
        }
    }

    private static void Core() {
        string occasion = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            string details = "There are no details but the error code." + "\nGUID: " + Guid.NewGuid() + "\nSee outer text for general info.";
            Exception innerException = new Exception(details);
            innerException.Source = "Location as referred below.";
            throw innerException;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            string message = "This is a crash test invoked @ " + occasion + "." + "\nSee inner exception for details.";
            Exception exception = new Exception(message, e);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

And debugged, The caught exception and inner exception will contain all the relevant content. Including the custom source in the inner exception.

> Where are those location info strings located in the exception object?

Usually in the `StackTrace`

> When/how do they get assigned?

When an exception is thrown they are populated by the runtime.

> The common language runtime (CLR) updates the stack trace whenever an exception is thrown in application code (by using the throw keyword). If the exception was rethrown in a method that is different than the method where it was originally thrown, the stack trace contains both the location in the method where the exception was originally thrown, and the location in the method where the exception was rethrown. If the exception is thrown, and later rethrown, in the same method, the stack trace only contains the location where the exception was rethrown and does not include the location where the exception was originally thrown.

Reference [Exception.StackTrace Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> Can I alter them and if so how?

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-inheritors)

> Notes to Inheritors
>
> The StackTrace property is overridden in classes that require control over the stack trace content or format.
>
> By default, the stack trace is captured immediately before an exception object is thrown. Use StackTrace to get stack trace information when no exception is being thrown.

You can consider creating a custom derived exception that inspects the base stack trace to make what ever desired alteration before returning the stack trace.

*Custom Exception*

```
public override StackTrace {
    get {
        string original = base.StackTrace;
        
        string result = //...altered message
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Reference [Implementing custom exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netcore-3.1#implementing-custom-exceptions)

Comment: What a fantastically great answer! So to verify that I'm getting it right - the way I tried to tamper with the contents of the exceptions, it's not a good idea, right? Those are meant to be handled by the system and, although containing settable properties, I'm not supposed to be there and horse around. It's a looking-but-not-touching situation, right? (Unless we inherit and do all the stuff explicitly.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten That about sums it up nicely.